# ASP.NET Web-Form C# Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am new to ASP.NET and I'm trying to make a WebShop.
The problem is that when I try to execute a method, I get an error.

I'm wondering if the problem is in the SQL tables?
Here's the method that produces the error

```
    public List<Product> productRead(int Product_ID)
            {

                IDataReader data = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(con, "Product_Read", Product_ID);
                List<Product> prod = new List<Product>();
                while(data.Read())
                {
                    Product pr = new Product();
                    pr.Product_ID=(int)data["Product_ID"];
                    pr.Product_Name=data["Product_Name"]as string;
                    pr.Product_Description=data["Product_Description"]as string;
                    pr.Product_Image =(char)data["Product_Image"];
                    pr.Product_Price=(int)data["Product_Price"];
                    pr.Product_Count=(int)data["Product_Count"];
                    prod.Add(pr);
                }
                return prod;
            }
```

And this is how I execute the above method:

```
    List<Product> pr = db.Instance.productRead(12);
                if (pr != null)
                {
                    foreach (Product product in pr)
                    {
                        Panel prPanel = new Panel();
                        ImageButton imgB = new ImageButton();
                        Label lbName = new Label();
                        Label lblPrice = new Label();

                        imgB.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + product.Product_Image;
                        imgB.PostBackUrl = "~/Home.aspx?id=" + product.Product_ID;
                        lbName.Text = product.Product_Name;
                        lblPrice.Text = "$" + product.Product_Price;

                        prPanel.Controls.Add(imgB);
                        prPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br/>" });
                        prPanel.Controls.Add(lbName);
                        prPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br/>" });
                        prPanel.Controls.Add(lblPrice);
                        pnlProducts.Controls.Add(prPanel);
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    pnlProducts.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "No product found !" });
                }
```

And the error:

```
Specified cast is not valid
```

Comment: The error is here : pr.Product_Image =(char)data["Product_Image"];

Comment: What line is the invalid cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this line in your code

```
imgB.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + product.Product_Image;
```

It looks like you're expecting `data["Product_Image"]` to be of type `string`, so perhaps change your cast to:

```
pr.Product_Image =(string)data["Product_Image"];
```

However, it would be more useful to you to add the lines:

```
var productImage = data["Product_Image"];
Type productImageType = productImage.getType();
```

You could then debug and step through your code and find the actual type of `data["Product_Image"]`. You could then amend the cast in the broken line to whatever it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you , for the answer , it works with var , i not get any error but on the page the image , does not appear ..

Comment: Thank you , i forget to change in the Product class , the Product_Image type , i was char and i make it string , i now it working :D.